# Not able to set stacked labels in framework7

Tags: html-framework-7

i am not able to set stacked labels in framework7.
Here is my code:-

```
    <div class="list">
    <ul>
    <li class="item-content item-input">
<div class="item-inner">
<div class="item-title item-label">Name</div>
    <div class="item-input-wrap">
<input type="text" name="name" />
    <span class="input-clear-button"> 
    </span>
 </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>![check this image]
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6g5m.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trace your code, I have found a **space** between `item- label`, and if you remove it your code will be work nice. you can check you example from here: [jsfiddle Live Exapmle](http://jsfiddle.net/cof9zexk/)

> Advice: You can use a tab button in keyboard to get sorted code that
>   will make your code easy to read and trace like this:

```
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    ...
    <li class="item-content item-input">
      <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-title item-label">Name</div>
        <div class="item-input-wrap">
          <input type="text" name="name">
          <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am still having same problem

Comment: Then issue from your code, maybe theirs wrong in your include css file, any thing override it....get a sample from fiddle...or make sure theres no error js in console

Comment: can you please put you'r Main Html layout? and main app js code?

Comment: or if you can check console if theres any error? ...also make sure thats app script refer to existing id

Comment: @SheikhHaziq You see a white blank page since you set class not id for app...change it to id and code will be work truth...http://jsfiddle.net/cof9zexk/1/

Comment: Can i use the same in ios.. if yes then how

Comment: I have included framework.ios.min.css but it is not working